# Simplify test for divisibility by all numbers 1…20

Tags: ruby, mathematics

```
def divisible?(n)
  if n % 1 == 0 &&
    n % 2 == 0 &&
    n % 3 == 0 &&
    n % 4 == 0 &&
    n % 5 == 0 &&
    n % 6 == 0 &&
    n % 7 == 0 &&
    n % 8 == 0 &&
    n % 9 == 0 &&
    n % 10 == 0 &&
    n % 11 == 0 &&
    n % 12 == 0 &&
    n % 13 == 0 &&
    n % 14 == 0 &&
    n % 15 == 0 &&
    n % 16 == 0 &&
    n % 17 == 0 &&
    n % 18 == 0 &&
    n % 19 == 0 &&
    n % 20 == 0
    return true
  else 
    return false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ruby refactor: use [Enumerable.all?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
def divisible?(n)
  (1..20).all? { |x| n % x == 0 }
end
```

Mathematical refactor:calculate the least common multiple of the integers in the range ([Integer#lcm](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-lcm) is available from Ruby 1.9):

```
def divisible?(n)
  n % (1..20).reduce(:lcm) == 0
end
```

This second snippet is, of course, more efficient once you pre-calculate `(1..20).reduce(:lcm)` only once and store it somewhere.

Comment: Would the first example benefit from 20..1 rather than 1..20? Less values of n are divisible by the higher divisors, leading to faster exit. Checking for factors seems like a case where premature optimisation is reasonable. (I don't know Ruby, maybe 1..20 is not equivalent to the big series of ifs in the question?)

Comment: @Sean: yeah, good point, you could write `(1..20).reverse_each.all? ...`. Anyway, one you've decided to do it in a mathematically sound way you might as well go for the second snippet, which is simple enough to understand and much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're doing this, which is a pretty egrigious use of if/else:

```
if boolean
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

If the branches of your if/else are `return true` and `return false`, you should just return the condition you're testing! In Ruby, you don't even need `return`, just let the condition "fall off" the end of the method.

Ignoring the ability to clean up your condition itself, a first pass at cleaning up your function could be:

```
def divisible?(n)
  n % 1 == 0 &&
  n % 2 == 0 &&
  n % 3 == 0 &&
  n % 4 == 0 &&
  n % 5 == 0 &&
  n % 6 == 0 &&
  n % 7 == 0 &&
  n % 8 == 0 &&
  n % 9 == 0 &&
  n % 10 == 0 &&
  n % 11 == 0 &&
  n % 12 == 0 &&
  n % 13 == 0 &&
  n % 14 == 0 &&
  n % 15 == 0 &&
  n % 16 == 0 &&
  n % 17 == 0 &&
  n % 18 == 0 &&
  n % 19 == 0 &&
  n % 20 == 0
end
```